# Correct (line-color) transition from one iterator to another

Tags: css, jsp, struts2

I'm working with two lists that I want to display in a JSP file. I have colored the lines of the lists depending on if their status (of the iterator) is even or odd. The problem is that I  first have an iterator which shows the color correctly, and after that I have another iterator which should start with the opposite color of what the first iterator ended with. Right now it depends on the status of the first one.

Say the first one has two lines
 1. odd
 2. even

The second iterator starts with:
1. odd
2. even

That is good. But if the first list has three objects then it will result like this:
(first)
1. odd
2. even
3. odd
(second)
1. odd
2. even

There are two 'odd' in a row, which means these lines will have the same color.

I want to start with even or odd on the second iterator depending on what the first one ended up with. Is there any smart way to do this?

**EDIT:**

```
<s:iterator var="men" value="men" status="rowstatus">
<tr class="<s:if test="#rowstatus.odd == true ">odd</s:if><s:else>even</s:else>">
<td><property value="name"/></td>
<td><property value="age"/></td>
<td><property value="length"/></td>
</tr>
</s:iterator>

<s:iterator var="women" value="women" status="rowstatus">
<tr class="<s:if test="#rowstatus.odd == true ">odd</s:if><s:else>even</s:else>">
<td><property value="name"/></td>
<td><property value="age"/></td>
<td><property value="length"/></td>
</tr>
</s:iterator>
```

Comment: Yes, there are. Can you show a sample generated HTML (view source -> copy -> paste here... the relevant part only), or fill a [fiddle](http://jsFiddle.net/) ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, you can (and should) do this with CSS only, without apply specific classes.

Having the following, semplified JSP code:

```
<table id="myTable">

    <s:iterator value="men">
        <tr>
            <td><property value="name"/></td>
            <td><property value="age"/></td>
            <td><property value="length"/></td>
        </tr>
    </s:iterator>

    <s:iterator value="women">
        <tr>
            <td><property value="name"/></td>
            <td><property value="age"/></td>
            <td><property value="length"/></td>
        </tr>
    </s:iterator>

</table>
```

you can apply the simple odd/even rule of [nth-child](http://css-tricks.com/how-nth-child-works/) (in a CSS file, or in a style block in the `<head>` section of your page):

```
<style>
    table#myTable tr:nth-child(odd) {
        background-color : white;
    }
    table#myTable tr:nth-child(even) {
        background-color : silver;
    }
</style>
```

Check out the <kbd>[Running example](http://jsfiddle.net/AndreaLigios/mAS3q/)</kbd>

Comment: Definitely a better direction; I almost never use `nth-child` but I suppose this is a case where I really should.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any reason to do this work on the view layer, especially since there's no clever way to do this without setting an additional variable to hold state across the iterators.

Combine the lists on the server side instead, particularly since there's no functional difference in each row's content. Doing essentially the exact same work twice in the view layer is wasteful and confusing.

Unrelated, but the `== true` is redundant and verbose.

Comment: Actually this is just a very simplified view of the code. There are differences on the two lists, but maybe I should try to combine them anyway. Thanks!